# Is It Possible to Query GeoJson?

Tags: geojson, google-maps

I am able to extract geometries from a shape created by the Google Maps DrawingManager class and also put polygons on the map using the the data.loadGeoJson call.

Now I want to do a spatial selection of the polygons that are within the DrawingManager object so I can extract their attributes. Is it possible with the Google Maps API? I know that I can do this by sending the geometries of the shape to a PHP program that can do a query on a spatial database, but I would like to do this completely on the browser.